# work out the value of a - b from the identity $ax+18=2(x-b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

How do I solve the following question?

> You are given the algebraic identity:
> $ax+18=2(x-b)$
>
> Work out the values of $a-b$

Comment: $2 - \dfrac{18}{-2} = ?$

Comment: 11 .but how did you get it?  Explain please

Comment: "Algebraic identity" means that it is true for all values of $x$, i.e. the coefficients of the powers of $x$ must be equal.

Answer (score 2):

The given equality can be written as follows:

> $ax+18=2(x-b)$
> or, $ax+18=2x-2b$
> or, $(a-2)x+(18+2b)=0$
>
> Science this is an identity in $x$ ,it follows that
>
> $a-2=0 , 18+2b=0$
>
> Thus $a=2$ and $b=-9$
> Hence, $a-b=2-(-9)=11$